# How to install Kali Linux tools in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, kali, kali-linux-tools

[image]

I want to install Kali Linux tools in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But I'm getting this error message. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the second command in the screen-shot. I guess your pull from git failed because there already is a folder by the name katoolin in current directory. You will have to use `rm -rf katoolin` to remove the folder and its content.

Because of this failure, katoolin.py is not downloaded and chmod command fails to find it. Hence, the error.

Comment: yeah thats working, even i changed name of directory then also it is working.